Comedy where woman attempts to seduce her way out of being kidnapped?
This movie probably came out in the 90's or 00's but no later. It seemed like an a raunchy teen comedy. There's this one specific scene I remember for some reason: a brunette young adult is tied to a chair, I think she's in the basement of the main characters house but like I said it's a comedy so she's not crying and freaking out or anything. At some point one of the guys who knows she's tied up feeds her a burger and the sauce falls off and drips down her shirt and she attempts to seduce him in order to get untied so she can escape. I think the main character has cameras in his house so he's watching this all go down. 
This is all I remember from this movie.

It's a scene from Saving Silverman Where Steve Zahn (Wayne) and Jack Black (J.D.) kidnap Amanda Peet (Judith) to stop her from marrying their friend
Here's the scene




Thank you so much! It's been driving me crazy for the longest time lol

@Jkane  happy to help!
